# sublime text 2 autocomplete codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2

frustrated and hopelessly question.

so i downloaded sublime text 2 for first time, i installed packagemanager and a autocomplete.php file from

> https://github.com/martinredola/sublimetext2-codeigniter-completions

now question is, how can i setup syntax autocomplete for codeigniter+html+css and disable all other irrelevant odd autocompelete list that pop up !!!

i'm looking for some one who tell me steps he did to make prefect workflow for codeigniter development using sublime text 2.

thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 11):

There is.

Install [Sublime Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control)

Then open "Package Control", choose "Package Control: Install Package".
Type in "CodeIgniter" and install the package "CodeIgniter Snippets".

Answer (score 1):

codeigniter snippet doesn't properly work with sublime text 2. I use this package with sublime text 3 and i don't have problems and if you add the sublimelinter package you can do very nice things.

You must install the package control first, the instructions are in the page

https://packagecontrol.io/installation

then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and write "install package", a full list of applications will be shown then search Codeigniter Snippet and hit enter, repeat the process for sublime linter and it's done

Answer (score 0):

Trust me,  I have been down this route many times. In the end, simply it is not worth it. Codeigniter is just not setup for easy autocomplete items.

I use PHPStorm as well as sublime text 2 for work with codeigniter, and even phpstorm which is a commercial product does not have support for codeigniter. There are much more valuable things to setup in a developement enviroment for php, for example do you have a debugger? That was another thing that really helped with my codeigniter development.

I do not use it all the time, usually I like to use a lightweight solution like sublime text 2, but when you are working on pure php code and cant always just set var_dump and print_r statements everywhere - a debugger really helps.